# How do I interface my UDPClient class with an Android Activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, text, dynamic

I have written (credit where credit is due - with significant help from my friend M.P) a UDP Client which runs as a Java program. For example, I run it via command prompt and I get my received data blasted into the console.

I would now like to have that data/text via console be "blasted"/displayed on my android device.

Here is the UDPClient Code:

```
public class UDPClient extends Thread
{
    private boolean abort = false;

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Starting new UDPClient thread");

        int port = 8384;

        DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;

        try
        {
            clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

            System.out.println("host = " + clientSocket.getLocalAddress());
            System.out.println("port = " + clientSocket.getLocalPort());

            byte[] receiveData = new byte[2048];

            while (!abort)
            {
                System.out.println("Waiting for data...");
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

                int packetLength = receivePacket.getLength();
                byte[] packetData = receivePacket.getData();

                String hexString = Utils.byteArrayToHex(packetData, packetLength);
                System.out.println("Received " + packetLength + " bytes: " + hexString);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (clientSocket != null)
        {
            clientSocket.close();
        }

        abort = false;

        System.out.println("UDPClient thread stopped.");
    }

    public void finish()
    {
        abort = true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        UDPClient client = new UDPClient();
        Thread thread = new Thread(client);
        client.start();

        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String sentence = "";

        System.out.println("Type QUIT (or use CTRL+C) to terminate...");
        do
        {
            sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        }
        while (!sentence.toUpperCase().contains("QUIT"));

        client.interrupt();
        client.finish();
        client.join();
    }
}
```

How would I go about converting all of my System Printouts to real time updated text boxes displayed in my activity? Many thanks.

Daniel

Comment: Take the thread as is, start it but post results to a UI handler & display them: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply Zapl :)